# Set default text for RichHtmlField

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 to edit a page layout file (*.aspx). I tried to set a default text to a RichHtmlField using its "Html" property, but it is not working. I tried the "Text" property and it's also not working. How do I make it work?

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="PageContent" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" MinimumEditHeight="400px" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" Html="<html><span><p>Objectives</p></span></html>" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Publishing:HtmlEditor This will allow you to set the HTML property. I am using this in a custom application page in Visual Studio so i have no idea if this will work in SharePoint Designer. My need was to have the default html editing textbox. It works on our environment like this:

```
        <Publishing:HtmlEditor ID="htmlEditor" BorderWidth="1" BorderStyle="Solid" runat="server" />
        <div ID="HtmlEditorTextBox" visible="false" runat="server" style="background-color: #F0F0F0; color: rgb(84, 84, 84); border:1px solid gray;width:400px;height:200px;overflow:auto;"></div>
```

In code-behind i can address the editor like this:

```
        htmlEditor.Field = new RichHtmlField();
        htmlEditor.Field.HasInitialFocus = false;
        htmlEditor.Field.ControlMode = Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControlMode.New;
        htmlEditor.Field.EnableViewState = true;
        htmlEditor.Field.AllowReusableContent = false;
        htmlEditor.Field.MinimumEditHeight = "200px";
        htmlEditor.Html = "<b>Hello</b>";
        HtmlEditorTextBox.InnerHtml = "<b>Hello</b>";
```

Make sure you have this include in your aspx page:

```
<%@Register TagPrefix="Publishing" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls"%>
```

Comment: Using the what?

Comment: adapted my answer, the tag was stripped out, sorry about that

Comment: I renamed RichHtmlField to HtmlEditor. Then when I edit a page, I got an exception "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Can you show me how to use HtmlEditor?

Comment: adapted my answer again ;-)

Comment: Not sure, as you instantiate a new RichHtmlField object on the first line of the second code block...